# Too many columns resulting in `PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of filepaths in the first column of a dataframe.  My goal is to create a second column that represents file categories, with categories reflecting the words in the filepath.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'filepath':  ['C:/barracuda/document.doc', 'C:/dog/document.doc', 'C:/cat/document.doc']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Animal"] =(df['filepath'].str.contains("dog|cat",case=False,regex=True))

df["Fish"] =(df['filepath'].str.contains("barracuda",case=False))

df = df.loc[:, 'filepath':'Fish'].replace(True, pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns))

df = df.loc[:, 'filepath':'Fish'].replace(False,np.nan)

def squeeze_nan(x):
    original_columns = x.index.tolist()
    squeezed = x.dropna()
    squeezed.index = [original_columns[n] for n in range(squeezed.count())]

    return squeezed.reindex(original_columns, fill_value=np.nan)

df = df.apply(squeeze_nan, axis=1) 
print(df)
```

This code works.  The problem arises when I have 200 statements beginning with `df['columnName'] =`.  Because I have so many, I get the error:

`PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling frame.insert many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use newframe = frame.copy()`

To fix this I have tried:

```
dfAnimal = df.copy

dfAnimal['Animal'] = dfAnimal['filepath'].str.contains("dog|cat",case=False,regex=True)

dfFish = df.copy
dfFish["Fish"] =dfFish['filepath'].str.contains("barracuda",case=False)

df = pd.concat(dfAnimal,dfFish)
```

The above gives me errors such as `method object is not iterable` and `method object is not subscriptable`.  I then tried `df = df.loc[df['filepath'].isin(['cat','dog'])]` but this only works when 'cat' or 'dog' is the only word in the column. How do I avoid the performance error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating all your new columns in a dict, and then convert that dict into a dataframe, and then use `pd.concat` to add the resulting dataframe (containing the new columns) to the original dataframe:

```
new_columns = {
    'Animal': df['filepath'].str.contains("dog|cat",case=False,regex=True),
    'Fish': df['filepath'].str.contains("barracuda",case=False),
}

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_columns)
df = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1)
```

Added to your original code, it would be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'filepath':  ['C:/barracuda/document.doc', 'C:/dog/document.doc', 'C:/cat/document.doc']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


##### These are the new lines #####

new_columns = {
    'Animal': df['filepath'].str.contains("dog|cat",case=False,regex=True),
    'Fish': df['filepath'].str.contains("barracuda",case=False),
}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_columns)
df = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1)

##### End of new lines #####

df = df.loc[:, 'filepath':'Fish'].replace(True, pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns))

df = df.loc[:, 'filepath':'Fish'].replace(False,np.nan)

def squeeze_nan(x):
    original_columns = x.index.tolist()
    squeezed = x.dropna()
    squeezed.index = [original_columns[n] for n in range(squeezed.count())]

    return squeezed.reindex(original_columns, fill_value=np.nan)

df = df.apply(squeeze_nan, axis=1) 
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks @richardec. Could you possibly write out your solution code in full?  I'm not understanding where I call `dfFish`?

Comment: Ultimately, what you're doing wrong is `dfFish = df.copy`. It should be `dfFish = df.copy()` (with the `()` added)

Comment: So after this line `df = df.apply(squeeze_nan, axis=1)`, add this line: `df = df.copy()`

Comment: @oymonk did it work? :)

Comment: No, but I also think I'm not quite following you.  Could you write out the code in full?  I get an error on `pd.concat`

Comment: Yes, I'll write it out in full. Note that your second code snippet - only your first one.

Comment: @oymonk after studying the problem a bit more, I came up with a different solution. Please check my answer now :)